# Copy Files from Previous Installation

Tags: windows-8, inno-setup

To fit Win 8 requirements, I need to copy a data file (`data.mpd`) from the install directory of the previous installation (typically `c:\ProgramFiles` but users could have changed to something else) to a new directory `c:\User\....`

How can I:

- Get the path of the previous install
- check if the file data.mpd exists
- Copy that file to the C:\Users...

Comment: If I get it right, you want to get the path of the previous installation of your application, check if there's the `data.mpd` file and copy that file into the `C:\Users\..` folder, is that right ?

Comment: Yes ... The point is that it can be located at C:\ProgramFiles (as this is the default dir proposed by the InnoSetup) but this is not guaranteed (user could have change the default dir) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use the `WizardForm.PrevAppDir` property, which holds the folder path, where the installer with a certain `AppId` had previously installed the application (empty if it was not yet installed). Note that this property is filled after the wizard form is initialized, so read it after the `InitializeWizard` event.

For your task, I would do this operation at the pre-installation step, so for the [`CurStepChanged`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#CurStepChanged) event method, I would write something like:

```
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  DataFilePath: string;
begin
  // check if the current step is pre-installation step and if the
  // application had been previously installed; if so, then...
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) and (WizardForm.PrevAppDir <> '') then
  begin
    // build and store the path to the Data.mpd file from the prev.
    // installation path
    DataFilePath := AddBackslash(WizardForm.PrevAppDir) + 'Data.mpd';
    // check, if that Data.mpd file exists; if so, then...
    if FileExists(DataFilePath) then
      // copy it to the target directory; if it fails, show error message
      if not FileCopy(DataFilePath, <your new directory here>, False) then
        MsgBox('Copying of the Data.mpd failed!', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... But, I guess, I'm a quite basic InnoSetup user... I never use the support classes... Do you have a sample for that kind of use ?

Comment: It's right in the answer... The code I've posted you'll just paste into your script file and replace the string `<your new directory here>` with the folder you want the `Data.mpd` file be copied since you didn't specified the concrete folder (you've said only `C:\Users...`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `DisableDirPage=auto`.  This will prevent people from changing the install path on an upgrade.

Then have your application (not the installer) detect this file in its own folder and copy it to the per-user folder.  This will give you the most robust behaviour in case multiple users run your application (which is the whole point of having per-user data).